# Find a record between two dates MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to find records in my DB that's end_date is within 24 hours of the current time.

Here is the query I am currently running

```
select *
FROM record r
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN r.end_date AND DATE_ADD(r.end_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY);
```

This doesn't bring back any of the records with an end_date within 24 hours, am I using the DATE_ADD function wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
select *
FROM record r
where
r.end_date >= date_add(now(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```